# AWS Sagemaker failure after successful training "ClientError: Artifact upload failed:Insufficient disk space"

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm training a network using custom docker image. First training with 50.000 steps everythig was ok, when I tried to increase to 80.000, I got error: "ClientError: Artifact upload failed:Insufficient disk space", I just increased the steps number.. this is weird to me. There are no errors in the cloudwatch log, my last entry is:

> Successfully generated graphs: ['pipeline.config', 'tflite_graph.pb',
>   'frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'tflite_graph.pbtxt',
>   'tflite_quant_graph.tflite', 'saved_model', 'hyperparameters.json',
>   'label_map.pbtxt', 'model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001',
>   'model.ckpt.meta', 'model.ckpt.index', 'checkpoint']

Which basically means that those files have been created because is a simple:

```
    graph_files = os.listdir(model_path + '/graph')
```

Which disk space is talking about? Also looking at the training job I see from the disk utilization chart that the rising curve peaks at 80%...
I expect that after the successful creation of the aforementioned files, everything is uploaded to my s3 bucket, where no disk space issues are present. Why 50.000 steps is working and 80.000 is not working? 
It is my understanding that the number of training steps don't influence the size of the model files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding volume size to the training job selecting "additional storage volume per instance (gb)" to 5GB on the creation seems to solve the problem. I still don't understand why, but problem seems solved.

Comment: could you provide some instructions on how to increase the additional storage volume? Either through the GUI or programatically would be amazing

Comment: through the GUI is trivial, when you create a training job there is a text field to specify the additional storage for the instance.

Comment: thanks for the info, I can't work out how to do it though :/ under training job dashboard I just see `Additional volume size (GB)` is set to `30` but there is no way to edit it

Comment: If you click on "Create training job", then under "Resource configuration" you have a text field "Additional storage volume per instance (GB)" which contains by default "1" and you can change it.. I cannot help you more here.. please open a new question in that's not clear.

Comment: thanks for your help I have fixed my problem, I am creating a training job [via Sagemaker's Estimator class](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase) (using Huggingface), you can set it programatically here `sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase( ... , volume_size=50)`

Answer (score 1):

When the Sagemaker training completes, the model from `/opt/ml/model` directory in container will be uploaded to S3. If the model to be uploaded is too large then that error `ClientError: Artifact upload failed:...` will be thrown.
And, increasing the `volume size` will fix the problem *superficially*. But the model in most cases does not have to be that large, right?

Note that the odds are your model itself is not too large but you're saving your checkpoints to `/opt/ml/model` as well (bug).
And, in the end, sagemaker tries to pack everything (model and all checkpoints) in order to upload to S3. Thereby, not having sufficient volume. Hence, the error. You can confirm if this is the reason by checking the size of your uploaded `model.tar.gz` file on S3.[image]

> Why 50.000 steps is working and 80.000 is not working?

With 80,000 steps, the number of checkpoints have also increased, and the final `model.tar.gz` file which is to uploaded on S3 has become too big that it can't even fit in current volume.

Comment: this is useful info but a bit incomplete, what are the practical steps to solve this problem? Use a larger training instance?

Comment: @Matt, simply don't store your checkpoints at `/opt/ml/model` such that the directory contains only the trained 'model' (no checkpoints) by the end of training; Thus, `model.tar.gz` will be small in size.
Pick any other directory for saving checkpoints.

Comment: @HamzaLiaqat it is not clear to me how to do this when using the HF wrapper – the `--output_dir` parameter is [explicitly used both for checkpoints and final model](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/v4.17.0/src/transformers/training_args.py#L416)